# cnames & URL redirects

Tags: redirect, subdomain, cname, forward

I was really hoping someone may be able to help me.

My goal is to have all 3 of the URL samples below redirect to the same place, specifically to http://deals.domain.com/index.html?parameter=variable

Notes:
(1) 'deals' is a CNAME within domain.com for another.domain.com
(2) 'deals' is a subdomain within domain.com which has a URL redirection set up to point to the goal URL above.

So far...

1. www.domain.com --- this is redirecting fine
2. domain.com --- this is redirecting fine
3. deals.domain.com --- this one does not appear to be redirecting.  When you type it in, it remains in the address bar and does not seem to take into account the variables after the ? in the goal URL (even though ultimately they are not shown in the address bar, but they do lead to a difference in Web content being shown).  It is however showing the basic content of another.domain.com

Maybe it is not wise to have the same thing 'deal' be both a CNAME as well as s subdomain; however, the CNAME is absolutely necessary so not sure how to get around this?

Within my ISP, I have set up the Zone records in the Domain section; but not sure I really understand because I can definitely see the CNAME record sitting there, yet it still let me set up a subdomain in the hosting section in a folder which I specified, I thought it wouldn't allow that.

Grateful for any and all advice.

Kind regards,
Mike

Comment: Hi Mike. How could 'deals' be a CNAME and subdomain at once for 'domain.com'? Check out your question again.

Comment: Hello Stanimir, Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it.  I agree with you that both cannot co-exist.   I have added some more text to my last paragraph to explain better, but it still makes no sense to me.

Comment: how are you doing the redirection? Please post your .htaccess file in the question.

Comment: Hello Stanimir, Thank you again, hmm unfortunately I would need to ask a 3rd party for the .htaccess file and not sure if they will let me see it or change it.  I'll try!   Would the idea be to place a .htaccess file in the folder pointed to by deals subdomain which autoforwards to the designated URL?

Comment: That was the idea, yes. It seems that something is wrong with the redirection when it is working in just 2/3 of the cases.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the 'deals' CNAME in point 1 above, but retain the same functionality of a CNAME by adding code to the .htaccess file?   In other words, still do (2) above, but then place a .htaccess file within deals.domain.com to redirect to http://deals.domain.com/index.html?parameter=variable ... but at the same time deals.domain.com needs to point to the IP address of another.domain.com (the effect of point 1 above using the CNAME).

Comment: So basically if someone types in only http://DEALS.domain.com/ they will be forwarded to http://ANOTHER.domain.com/index.html?parameter=variable yet they will see in the address bar http://DEALS.domain.com/index.html?parameter=variable  (I have capitalised only to make those bits stand out :-)

Comment: But doing this all exclusively only with the use of the 'deals' subdomain and a .htaccess file.

Comment: Ultimately I just want someone to type in http://deals.domain.com and they are automatically redirected to http://deals.domain.com/AdditionalStuff.html; however, the part that confuses me is that 'deals' has also been set up as a CNAME for anotherDomain.com ... so I need to use 'deals.domain.com' to be able to show the content on 'anotherDomain.com' however it is a specific page on 'anotherDomain.com' that I want people to be directed to ... and because of the CNAME it is therefore http://deals.domain.com/AdditionalStuff.html      Is this actually possible?